# Getting " Expected ';' " in the visual studio immediate window

Tags: javascript, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging, immediate-window

I type something like `?311610.ToString()`, and it gives me the error saying `Expected ';'`

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

Sorry, I forgot to mention I was debugging javascript.

Comment: what happens if you type `?311610.ToString();`?

Comment: what is `?` in `?311610.ToString()`?

Comment: Just tried it with VS2008 immediate window, and it works for me (in VB.Net and C# projects). Anything else to mention?

Comment: @Kevin, the `?` is "print the result of".  It used to be BASIC shorthand for `PRINT`.

Comment: I was debugging some javascript code. I forgot to mention that bit.

Comment: Now I've tried `?311610.toString()`, but still the same result.